# How can I install Gentoo in this situation

Tags: system-installation, gentoo

Why does it nessesary to coincide the release version of stage3 and minimal install CD? Or can I install Gentoo with old minimal CD, but current stage?

Comment: It's been a while since I have installed gentoo, but the installation media shouldn't matter. As long as it can create partitions, and download the stage3 tarball.

Comment: What jordanm said. If you want to install from the stage3 tarball, you don't need any Gentoo CD. All you need is some running environment to be able to create your disk partition(s), filesystem, and get the stage3 copied into it.

Comment: Adding to the comment of the other @Tim: It is still important, that the live cd is built for the same architecture (x86 or amd64) you intend to install. You will not be able to finish a 64bit installation with a 32bit live cd and vice versa (the `chroot` step will fail). That said even a Ubuntu or grml cd would be fine.

Comment: @Tim : actually you can chroot from 64 bits to 32 bits using "linux32 chroot <mountpoint>"

Comment: @pgrandin Interesting. I never had the problem in this direction myself though.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the old minimal media will work fine for installing in almost all cases. If the media is really old (talking about 2006 or older), where you might run into problems is glibc and a few system packages during install: udev, sandbox are likely to be the most of the problem; and even then only if you intend on copying the kernel from the install media, or don't build a new kernel before some of those packages.